# Realistic metal textures

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, shaders

So guys i'm not the greatest when it comes to metallic textures, any other textures i can do. I can easily create a silver(Natural) metallic texture, But i cannot create a Green(Painted) Metallic texture. I am currently working on this Renault and I just cant seem to find the right way to create a good texture for it. What texture should I use to create the Metallic body of the Tank and how do i achieve this or apply it to the tank, do I create my own diffuse and glossy shader with a normal map or do I use a texture and give it a normal map and a glossy map. And how would I set this all up in the Nodes correctly with glossy shaders and Bump maps.
Thanks Guys.

[image: French Renault 600 Tank, Copyright of Sarsha W]

Comment: You probably just need a normal silver metal shader mixed with a paint shader, using a modified noise texture or any convincing pattern. So the material is either metal or paint, but not both.

Comment: Do you have a reference of what you hope to achieve? Adding an image to your question would be useful.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1PkSViBi-M) by Andrew Price shows a great method of creating Photorealistic Metal textures, and the best part is you only have to do it once, then you can save the Node group into your default file so you'll never have to create the material again. It is highly recommended you follow his [first tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3wghbZ-Vh4&t=8s) that teaches how to create photorealistic meterial to use with nonmetals, so you're caught up and not confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metal materials are **pure gloss** and if you want it painted then

1-It's metal that have been painted (like it's been sprayed with paint)
which is gloss shader mixed with a paint material using a mix shader and the Factor is an image texture made to tell blender where is gloss and where is paint

2-It's like metal that is factory painted
which is gloss with an image texture

note that metal has a **colored rim** light

for the best realistic result look up **PBR materials**

I recommend blender guru's tutorial ..2 videos that explain PBR materials the second one is about accurate metal materials but you need to see the first one

Comment: Hi Leo, Sorry I have already worked out this question. I did look into blender guru's tutorials and have come up with my own node set on PBR materials/shaders. Thanks for the assistance anyways